# How can I fill a column with values that are computed between two dates in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

| Date | Position | TrainerID | Win% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-09-03 | 4 | 1788 | 0 (0 wins, 1 race) |
| 2017-09-16 | 5 | 1788 | 0 (0 wins, 2 races) |
| 2017-10-14 | 1 | 1788 | 33 (1 win, 3 races) |

I want to compute on every row of the `Win%` Column the winning percentage, as above, for the races in the last 1000 days.

I tried something like this:

```
def compute_winning_percentage(a, b):
    return (a / b)*100

featured_data['Percentage win of trainer in the last 1000 days'] = featured_data.groupby('TrainerID').apply(
    compute_winning_percentage(len(featured_data.loc[featured_data.Position == 1]),
                               featured_data[featured_data.Position].cumcount()))
```

But I get an error and I have no idea how to insert the **last 1000 days** part.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a indicator column to represent the win, then group the indicator column by `TrainerID` and apply the `rolling` `mean` to calculate the winning percentage, finally `merge` the calculated percentage column with the original dataframe

```
# Create indicator column
df['win'] = df['Position'].eq(1) 

# Groupby and calculate rolling mean on indicator column
w = df.groupby('TrainerID').rolling('1000D', on='Date')['win'].mean().mul(100)

# Merge the result back to dataframe
df_new = df.merge(w.reset_index(name='Win_%'), on=['TrainerID', 'Date'])
```

---

```
>>> df_new

        Date  Position  TrainerID    win      Win_%
0 2017-09-03         4       1788  False   0.000000
1 2017-09-16         5       1788  False   0.000000
2 2017-10-14         1       1788   True  33.333333
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!