# Why do I get a different DataFrame size after merge?

Tags: python, pandas

I applied the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69963949/how-can-i-fill-a-column-with-values-that-are-computed-between-two-dates-in-panda/) on a larger DataFrame than the one presented as an example. The DataFrame has 27008 rows and 93 columns (the columns not mentioned in the example are not relevant here). The `w` in the example, the one that will be merged has also 27008 rows and a single column (the one containing the rolling win%). But, after the merge, the main DataFrame does not have 27008 rows, as I'd expect, but 162152 rows.

The code I used is this:

```
temp = featured_data.copy()
temp['Win'] = temp['Position'].eq(1)
w = temp.groupby('TrainerID').rolling('1000D', on='Date')['Win'].mean().mul(100).round(2)
featured_data = temp.merge(w.reset_index(name='Win% in the last 1000 days'), on=['TrainerID', 'Date'])
featured_data = featured_data.drop(columns='Win')
```

Where am I mistaking?

Comment: duplicate keys on either (or both) dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate keys on one or both dataframes.