# How can I fill a column with values that are computed between two dates in pandas, if I have repeating dates?

Tags: python, pandas

This question is a variation of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69963949/how-can-i-fill-a-column-with-values-that-are-computed-between-two-dates-in-panda), the only difference being that the dates can repeat in the rows of a DataFrame. So, the example would be:

| Date | Position | TrainerID | Win% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-09-03 | 4 | 1788 | 0 (0 wins, 1 race) |
| 2017-09-16 | 5 | 1788 | 0 (0 wins, 2 races) |
| 2017-10-14 | 1 | 1788 | 33 (1 win, 3 races) |
| 2017-10-14 | 3 | 1788 | 25 (1 win, 4 races) |

Is it possible to compute `Win%` in these conditions for the last 1000 days? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in the other solution is still correct; the issue is that `groupby` + `rolling` destroys the Index so it becomes problematic to align the result back to the original DataFrame.

In this case, you can `.reset_index` and use `max` (assuming a RangeIndex) to bring along the original Index. This allows you to aggregate, then align the result back.

I added an additional row at the end to show you how it enforces the 1000 day window.

```
# If your DataFrame doesn't have a RangeIndex this is required for the logic
#df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df['win'] = df['Position'].eq(1) 

s = (df.reset_index().groupby('TrainerID')
       .rolling('1000D', on='Date')
       .agg({'win': 'mean', 'index': 'max'})
       .reset_index(drop=True)
       .set_index('index')
       .mul(100))  
#              win
#index            
#0.0      0.000000
#1.0      0.000000
#2.0     33.333333
#3.0     25.000000
#4.0    100.000000

df['Win %'] = s
```

---

```
print(df)
        Date  Position  TrainerID    win       Win %
0 2017-09-03         4       1788  False    0.000000
1 2017-09-16         5       1788  False    0.000000
2 2017-10-14         1       1788   True   33.333333
3 2017-10-14         3       1788  False   25.000000
4 2027-10-14         1       1788   True  100.000000
```

Comment: And if I want to compute this for the last 1000 days?

Comment: @BogdanDoicin got it, should be fixed now.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you!